# Replace Quotations in records SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have records with quotations that I would like to replace with ''.

Example:

```
"ASKHELLO"SE   -->    ASKHELLO SE 
""HELLO""1     -->    HELLO 1
```

How can I do this in SQL Server?

I know replace function, but how do I get the pattern to check for to be any character other than `""`.

```
UPDATE
   wordname
SET
   wordname = REPLACE(deal, '"'+ '%', '')
```

This is incorrect. Help, please.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?  take records with text enclosed with quotations and replace with that text and a space?  do all records have the quotations or just a few?

Comment: Please define exactly what you want the result to be.  Do you want to replace double quotes with spaces?  Should consecutive double quotes result in multiple spaces?  Is it OK for there to be a leading or trailing space?

Answer (score 1):

I am adding another answer based on your comment about double spaces on my original answer.  ID in this case is arbitrary but I am huge fan of always having a primary key of some kind.  XML we meet again!

```
--Setup the Table
DECLARE @T TABLE (wordname VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('"ASKHELLO"SE'),('""HELLO""1')
SELECT * FROM @T

--DECLARE AND SET XML REPLACING " with spaces
DECLARE @XML XML = 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wordname ASC) AS "@ID",
      CONVERT(XML,'<PART>' + REPLACE(CAST(CAST(REPLACE(wordname, '"',' ') AS VARCHAR(25)) AS VARCHAR(max)),' ',' </PART><PART>') + '</PART>') AS Word
FROM      @T AS T
      FOR XML PATH('Node'), ROOT('Nodes'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
)
SELECT @XML


--SHRED THE XML (WHICH WILL REMOVE NULLS) AND TRIM
;WITH
SHRED AS
(
SELECT  ID = FieldAlias.value('(@ID)[1]','INT'),
       WordName = FieldAlias.value('(Word)[1]','varchar(max)')
FROM       @XML.nodes('/Nodes/Node') AS TableAlias(FieldAlias)
)
SELECT  S.ID,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(S.WordName)) AS WordName
FROM       Shred AS S
```

[image]

And it should be relatively trivial for you to update off the shredded result set at this point, but let me know if you need that too.  Replace the @T with your original table to pull off your data set.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE function does a global replace within a string. So u can do simple

```
UPDATE
   wordname
SET
   deal = REPLACE(deal, '"', '')
```

Assuming that "wordname" is your table and "deal" is a field you're replacing.

This will simple remove the double quotes. If you need to replace it with space use `' '` instead of `''`

Comment: `"ASKHELLO"SE` => `ASKHELLO SE` is what was asked for your code gives `ASKHELLOSE`

Comment: Not in the code example and *I would like to replace with ''*

Comment: Ok will wait for more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?  Try using LTRIM to strip off leading spaces after the replace.  Here's a quick example based on your code:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (wordname VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('"ASKHELLO"SE'),('""HELLO""1')
SELECT * FROM @T

SELECT  LTRIM(REPLACE(wordname, '"',' '))
FROM       @T
```

[image]

Comment: Two spaces between `HELLO` and `1`, but close. :D